# IndexedDB: Copy to different domain?

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

I'm switching domains and want to provide my users with the option to keep using the same IndexedDB on my new domain.

I guess, this is not possible from JavaScript due to the same-origin policy. However, my users are "technical proficient" and all use Chrome.

So is there a way my users can manually move the IndexedDB from one domain to another? Maybe some file copy operation in the Chrome user directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an iframe and `postMessage()` to transfer the data. Have the new domain open an iframe to the old domain and set up a `message` event listener. Have the old domain provide a page that, when opened, crawls the database and does a `postMessage()` to the parent window - specifying the *targetOrigin* parameter to restrict this to the correct new domain. You'll need to invent an appropriate message scheme for batching and signaling completion.

(In Chrome the backing store for Indexed DB includes the origin in the data itself so you can't simply move files.)

Comment: Is the origin easily editable in one of the data files (e.g., some kind of metadata file?) or is it hidden in some hard-to-edit binary format? (as you might have guessed already, my users are few and all of them are technical proficient enough to edit files in a hex editor) I would go for your suggested `postMessage()` approach (great idea!) only if the additional effort is really necessary :-)

Comment: The origin exists as a key prefix for for database metadata records within leveldb. There are an arbitrary number of leveldb table files in a directory, depending on the database history (compaction, etc) and entries could exist in any table file. Records are also compressed within the tables. So short answer: I don't think a human could do it. :( Writing a custom leveldb client and reimplementing Chrome's key comparison/decode routines is technically possible, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your time and insights, I'll give the export-import approach a go!

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1
export/import

```
objectstore.getall()  //and done on each store.
```

some transactions to add data to new site.

```
//a few createobjectstore()    
for(var i in myobject.length){
    objecstore.add(myobject[i]
}
```

OPTION 2
if chrome and using an chrome extension. i do not have page in front of me, but if you know id of your extension and another extension you can cross-site

i want to say chrome.runtime.message()  is used to talk between backpage of extension and other pages of extension, along with needing to commuicate with another site.