# Access IndexedDB Instance as different website in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Angular Application running over Electron that is already in production, however I've made an update that is not yet released that has a serious issue.

I use `IndexedDB` do store the application data, and as for now I've been loading the app internal website with
`mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html#');`

However I had to create a custom protocol with `registerBufferProtocol` for loading files and now I load them like this
`mainWindow.loadURL('customprotocol://localhost/index.html#');`

It seems that Electron thinks this is a different website, so instead of accessing the same `localStorage` and `indexedDB` instances it provides a new one.

I need to find a way to instantiate and load the main browser windows using my new protocol, but keeping the old app data accessible in the same way as before.

On the Developer Tools Window of the old version of my app shows the `localStorage` session belongs to `file://`

[image: Local Storage of the old app version belongs to file://]

However in the new App Version I made it shows that the `localStorage` session belongs to the other "new" site which loads with my custom protocol `fredata://localhost`

[image: Local Storage of the new app version belongs to fredata://localhost]

On the App Data path, the folder of all the different website files are still present, I was wondering if a simple rename would suffice, but I don't think it is that simple.

[image: App Data path of the IndexDB Folder displaying all the different website Instances Stored]

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I tried to rename the directories, but it doesn't work. I guess that the origin is stored somewhere inside the data, and according to this thread it seems complicated to modify it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820493/indexeddb-copy-to-different-domain

Comment: I managed to find a solution, it wasn't very clean in my opinion but it works. basically you had to override the file:// protocol, and serve the files myself that way.

Comment: Ok that’s what I did too, it prevents the use of a custom scheme but for my use I guess it’s good enough… Thank you!